# how can I get the TinyMce editor content with php

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, textarea

I am using TinyMce html editor for make my posts body...with a hard try I finally could to setup the tinimce.init() function and apear the editor face ..

Now my serious problem is getting the tinymce textarea content(words , sentences , symbols ,...) . I am newbie in javascript so if it is possible with php I will appreciate you to help me in that way.

and if there is no way so how can I get it in javascript .

it's my tinymce textarea:

```
<form action='post.php' class = 'form-group' name = 'myform'  id = 'myform'>
<textarea class='tinymce' id='tinyContent' name='tinyContent' ></textarea>
<input type='submit' value='create post'>
</form>
```

and in my post.php page:

```
$body=$_POST['tinyContent'];
print_r(stripslashes_deep($body));
```

but there is nothing

Comment: have you "saved" the content before submitting? http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.save

Comment: @PatrickEvans :really thanks for reply . I'm not so familiar with javascript ... where should I put this code?? and should I write the code exactly the same way that is in your link? without any return or variable?

Comment: @PatrickEvans : I updated my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324608/getting-data-from-tinymce-with-php-and-save-on-database  . please check it if you have time.